# How to extract strings from the list with an additional condition on previous elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

There are a long list of strings $s$ and two lists of substrings $s1$ and $s2$. I want to take all elements of $s$ which contain a substring from $s2$ and such that before it on no more than $n$ places there is a string containing a substring from $s1$. For example, if

```
s={"a","b1","c","b2","a","c","b3"};
s1={"a"} ;
s2={"b"};
n=2;
```

the result should be `{"b1","b3"}` because two previous to `"b2"` elements  don't contain substring `"a"`.

It can be done with the help of `Position`, creating and comparing two lists of elements positions with fragments from $s1$ and $s2$. Is there a more direct way without creating additional lists?

Comment: I note that each of the three methods posted produce different results.  I don't know which if any is correct.

Comment: I want to take another crack at this.  Please clarify: is a string containing both "a" and "b" to automatically be returned?

Comment: Yes, all strings containing "b" to be returned.

Comment: Andrew, certainly you don't mean any string anywhere containing "b" is to be returned, so I'm still not clear on that.  Please see my second answer and tell me which (if either) behavior is as you want.

Comment: You mean "such that in it's n previous positions there is at least one string containing a substring of s1"?

Comment: @Rojo Yes, a substring which is an element of $s1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second attempt, working on the assumption that `"axb"` should *not* be returned:

```
s = {"a", "b1", "c", "b2", "a", "c", "b3", "axb"};
s1 = {"a"};
s2 = {"b"};
n = 2;

f = (If[# > 0 && ! StringFreeQ[#2, s2], Sow@#2]; 
     If[! StringFreeQ[#2, s1], n, # - 1]) &;

Reap[Fold[f, 0, s]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {"b1", "b3"}
> ```

If `"axb"` *should* be returned, then:

```
f = (If[! StringFreeQ[#, s1], i = n, --i]; 
     If[i >= 0 && ! StringFreeQ[#, s2], Sow@#]) &;

Reap[i = 0; Scan[f, s]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {"b1", "b3", "axb"}
> ```

---

Since this answer was Accepted I guess I'm on the right path.  I shall provide an additional method designed for speed using `ListCorrelate` (inspired by R.M's answer) and `Pick`.

```
bin = 1 - Boole@StringFreeQ[s, #] &;

Pick[
  s,
  bin[s2] ListCorrelate[ConstantArray[1, n + 1], bin[s1], n + 1, 0] // Unitize,
  1
]
```

> ```
> {"b1", "b3", "axb"}
> ```

If you want the behavior that does not return `"axb"` use `ConstantArray[1, n]`.

Comment: @R.M I think I should combine the answers and include performance testing as they exchange places depending on the data.  Now is not the time however.  Poke me if I don't get back to it in 24 hours.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this counts as "creating additional lists", but it seems to work:

```
With[{s = {"a", "b1", "c", "b2", "a", "c", "b3"}, s1 = {"a"}, s2 = {"b"}, n = 2},
 Last /@ Select[Partition[s, n + 1, 1, {-1, -1}, {}],
                ! (StringFreeQ[Last[#], s2] || And @@ StringFreeQ[Most[#], s1]) &]]
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. It doesn't work for $n\ne2$, but probably it can be mended just changing `Partition` options.

Comment: Could you give an example of a case where this construction doesn't work? I have a possible tweak in mind, but I'd like to be sure if it'll work in those cases you mention...

Comment: It gives  `"b3"` for $n=3$ in this example and for $n=1$ produces an error message.

Comment: Try the current version now.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
ReplaceList[s,{___,p:Repeated[_,n]/;!StringFreeQ[StringJoin@p,s1],x_/;!StringFreeQ[x,s2],___}:>x]
```

Comment: Thanks. It could give repeated strings in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using `ListCorrelate`:

```
test[list_, pat1_, pat2_] /; ! StringFreeQ[Last@list, pat1] := 
    Last@list /; ! StringFreeQ[StringJoin@Most@list, pat2]
test[_, _, _] := ## &[]

ListCorrelate[ConstantArray[1, n + 1], s, {-1, -1}, {""}, ##2 &, test[{##}, s2, s1] &] 
(* {"b1", "b3"} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably similar to what you alluded to in the question but perhaps it is helpful anyway:

```
s = {"a", "b1", "c", "b2", "a", "c", "b3", "axb"};
s1 = {"a"};
s2 = {"b"};
n = 2;

Cases[
  s[[Max[1, # - n] ;; #]] & @@@ Position[StringFreeQ[s, s2], False],
  {x__, b_} /; ! StringFreeQ["" <> x, s1] :> b
]
```

> ```
> {"b1", "b3"}
> ```

If it is desired to return `"axb"` in the example above use `StringFreeQ[x <> b, s1]`

Comment: thanks, it work correctly if for `"b"` on a segment [#,#+n] there is only one element with `"a"`. Otherwise there will be multiple copies of the same string in the result.

Comment: @Andrew You're right of course.  I'm sorry but I don't have time to fix this now.

Comment: @Andrew I have revised this answer to address the problem.  Please let me know if it works.  I still do not know if you want to return e.g. `"axb"` automatically.